# How to define ffmpeg's path during compilation of another software?

Tags: make, ffmpeg, source, cmake

I'm trying to compile an opensource software that needs bleeding-edge ffmpeg, so I successfully compiled ffmpeg, but I don't want to run `make install` as it's not easy to be removed after my tests.

The sofware I'm compiling is Open Broadcaster Software (OBS for short), and it's using CMake for the `make` command. It searches for ffmpeg libs in the defaults folders, which of course are not the version the software needs, so the `make` command fails, not being able to find ffmpeg.

How can I set, in a temp variable or in the CMake files, where my ffmpeg is? I don't know if this is standard for CMake (which anyone with knowledge would know how to answer) or this was chosen by OBS's dev (which then I have to ask him about that).